# how to remove comma and strings after a comma in a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file with 10000 rows and 17 columns, looks like this:

```
Chr17 43633894  0.5 3.0103  2386    14.9269 6.85401 41.0732 42.8984 953 80848   9.41879 24.1244 26  11.961  87.4669 random1_1000
Chr17 45194841  0.401235    16.7362 2626    4.75178 3.2041  58.5842 59.7521 3534    93081   3.2038  59.9018 52  54.6311 3.08007 random1_1000
```

In some rows for some columns I have 2 values instead of one which are separated by comma "," from each other, like this row (3rd and 4th columns for instance):

```
Chr11 38465225  0.523952,0.5    4.67466,3.0103  2662    4.06441,3.73412 6.21149 53.0049,55.4167 58.8243 7269,408    92146   73.8888,21.1059 46.0485 62,1    4.06441,3.0103  3.8106  MAP_outliers
```

I want to find all of these comma in my file, remove comma and a value which comes after comma, get an output like this

```
Chr11 38465225    0.523952    4.67466  2662    4.06441 6.21149 53.0049 58.8243 7269    92146   73.8888 46.0485 62    4.06441  3.8106  MAP_outliers
```

any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {gsub(",[0-9].*", "", $i)}}; 1'
```

- `for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)` iterates over the field numbers
- `{gsub(",[0-9].*", "", $i)}` replaces everything after a comma followed by a digit and then anything with null; this is an in-place operation

**Example:**

```
% awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {gsub(",[0-9].*", "", $i)}}; 1' <<<'Chr11 38465225  0.523952,0.5    4.67466,3.0103  2662    4.06441,3.73412 6.21149 53.0049,55.4167 58.8243 7269,408    92146   73.8888,21.1059 46.0485 62,1    4.06441,3.0103  3.8106  MAP_outliers'
Chr11 38465225 0.523952 4.67466 2662 4.06441 6.21149 53.0049 58.8243 7269 92146 73.8888 46.0485 62 4.06441 3.8106 MAP_outliers
```

Comment: but I do not know in which rows I have comma!

Comment: @Anna1364 Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, yes. It worked. Sorry I did not get it in the beginning! Thanks you

Comment: No need of gsub and [0-9]; awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {sub(",.*", "", $i)}}; 1' is enough

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
sed 's/,[^[:blank:]]*//g' infile
```

Remove comma followed by anything which is not a white-spaces and all matches.

Comment: I prefer `sed -E 's/,\S*//g' `